# Trouble having modal show up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a button that opens a modal, I've followed a tutorial step by step but for some reason, it doesn't work, the button doesn't even seem clickable.

```js
const open = document.getElementById('open');
const modal_container = document.getElementById('modal_container');
const close = document.getElementById('close');

function show() {
  modal_container.classList.add('show')
}

function hide() {
  modal_container.classList.remove('show')
}

open.addEventListener('click', show);
close.addEventListener('click', hide);
```

```css
#modal_container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#modal_container.show {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

#modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="open">Click me</button>
<div id="modal_container">
  <div class="modal">
    <h1> Modal 1</h1>
    <p> Lorem ipsum... </p>
    <button type="button" id="close">Close me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code appears to work as expected.  In your browser, have you checked the development console for errors?  When you use the browser's script debugger to step through the executing JavaScript code, what specifically happens?

Comment: Do you mean the formatting isn't correct? Because you have `#modal` which is an id but your HTML is using it as a class `<div class="modal">` https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/mbzwctp5/